# Import fixture data from test in ember-cli

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-cli

I am storing a static json file in `tests/fixtures/`. The test is in `tests/acceptance/`  When I try to load the fixture and run `ember test --server` I get stuck in the "Building..." state the loading statement that I am using is `import allProjectsData from 'new-i/tests/fixtures/projects.json'` where the project name is new-i.

Any ideas on how to load json data for use in an acceptance test?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the npm package [`ember-cli-pretender`](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-pretender) to mock out http requests, and import fixture data to be returned in those fake endpoints.

To import the JSON in similar syntax to your other imports, I'd make a separate `fixtures/` folder in your `app/` dir. Then make your name conventioned `.js` files export like this

```
export default {
    "json_data": "here"
};
```

Then just import the data in your acceptance test the same way are in your example above: `import data from 'app/fixtures/file_name_no_extension';`

**NOTE** If you want these fixtures in your `tests/` dir you need to import them with a relative path: `import data from '../../fixtures/file_name_no_extension';`